# Problema no envio de múltiplos emails

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema, fiz um `script` para enviar múltiplos emails, o problema é que ele só envia para o primeiro resultado do `select`,e já sai do `loop` sem mandar para os que faltam, segue abaixo o código. Se alguém souber oque pode ser isso ajudaria muito:

```html
<?php
include('../../config.php');

$evento = $_POST['evento'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg = $_POST['corpo'];

    $select_ins = "SELECT inscrito, evento FROM inscricoes WHERE status = 'Aprovado' AND evento =".$evento." ";

$insc = mysql_query($select_ins) or die(mysql_error());

while($ins = mysql_fetch_array($insc)){
    $select_part = "SELECT nome, email, telefone FROM inscrito WHERE id=".$ins['inscrito'];
             $parts = mysql_query($select_part) or die(mysql_error());
             $part = mysql_fetch_array($parts);

             $select_eve= "SELECT nome FROM eventos WHERE id=".$ins['evento'];
             $eves = mysql_query($select_eve) or die(mysql_error());
             $eve = mysql_fetch_array($eves);

    $email = $part['email'];
    $msg = str_replace('#nome', $part['nome'], $msg);
    $msg = str_replace('#telefone', $part['telefone'], $msg);
             $msg = str_replace('#evento', $eve['nome'], $msg);

    date_default_timezone_set ('America/Sao_Paulo');
             $corpo = "Email de teste para usuarios";

                require ('../../../aws/aws-autoloader.php');

                // Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
                // This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
                define('SENDER', 'Eventos<noreply@intelligenceeventos.com.br>');

                // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
                // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
                define('RECIPIENT', $email);

                // Replace us-west-2 with the AWS region you're using for Amazon SES.
                define('REGION','us-east-1');

                define('SUBJECT', $assunto); //Assunto digitado pelo Administrador
                define('BODY', $corpo);


                $client = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory(array(
                    'version'=> 'latest',
                    'region' => REGION,
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key' => 'AJSIDSAJIDSAJIDSAID',
                        'secret' => 'SOKAODSAKDOSADSA86SD6SA2',
                        )
                ));

                $request = array();
                $request['Source'] = SENDER;
                $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
                $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
                $request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = BODY;

                try {
                     $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
                     $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
                     echo("Emails enviados com sucesso! ");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                     echo("Erro ao enviar, confira se o email informado esta correto.");
                     echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
                }



}
```

Comment: pq vc define as constantes dentro do while? elas são constantes pq ... seu valor não muda ...

Comment: Realmente, porem tirei as contantes de dentro mais continua com o mesmo problema, envia pra o primeiro e pra os outro não

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? coloque isso no início, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Nenhum erro, mas percebi que ele esta fazendo o numero de loops corretos, tanto que chega mais de um email na caixa de entrada, do primeiro resultado, não sei porque o foreach não esta trazendo os outros dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi substituir as contantes por variáveis, tirando assim de dentro do loop. O código ficou assim:

```html
<?php
$ano = date('Y');

//verificação de evento
$evento = $_POST['evento'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg = $_POST['corpo'];

require ('../../../aws/aws-autoloader.php');
define('SENDER', 'teste@gmail.com');
define('REGION','us-east-1');
define('SUBJECT', $assunto);

$client = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',
    'region' => REGION,
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        )
));

if($evento == 0){
 $select_ins = "SELECT DISTINCT inscrito, evento FROM inscricoes WHERE status = 'Aprovado' GROUP BY inscrito";
}else{
 $select_ins = "SELECT inscrito, evento FROM inscricoes WHERE status = 'Aprovado' AND evento =".$evento;
}

$insc = mysql_query($select_ins, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());

while($ins = mysql_fetch_array($insc)){
             $msg = $_POST['corpo'];
 $select_part = "SELECT nome, email, telefone FROM inscrito WHERE id=".$ins['inscrito']." ";
             $parts = mysql_query($select_part) or die(mysql_error());
             $part = mysql_fetch_array($parts);

             $select_eve= "SELECT nome FROM eventos WHERE id=".$ins['evento'];
             $eves = mysql_query($select_eve) or die(mysql_error());
             $eve = mysql_fetch_array($eves);

 $email = $part['email'];
 $msg = str_replace('#nome', $part['nome'], $msg);
 $msg = str_replace('#telefone', $part['telefone'], $msg);
             $msg = str_replace('#evento', $eve['nome'], $msg);

 date_default_timezone_set ('America/Sao_Paulo');
             $corpo = "Mensage Aqui";

                $request = array();
                $request['Source'] = SENDER;
                $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array($email);
                $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
                $request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $corpo;

                $result = $client->sendEmail($request);

                sleep(1);
}
                try {
                     $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
                     echo("Emails enviados com sucesso! ");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                     echo("Erro ao enviar, confira se o email informado esta correto.");
                     echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
                }
```